# How do I share global variables between modules in processing.py?

Tags: python, processing

I am quite aware of most methods in python, but nothing seems to work in processing.py.

Originally, I've just tried this:

```
#####file: main.pyde
def setup():
  global thing
  thing = loadShape("param.svg")
  #bla-bla-bla

def draw():
  #bla-bla-bla

#####file: control.py
from main import thing
#bla-bla-bla
```

Would be perfect. But the problem is that, apparently, you cannot import the main .pyde file as a module: it keeps returning "No module named main".

Next, I decided to try to introduce a separate allglobal module:

```
#####file: allglobal.py
thing = loadShape("param.svg")

#####file: control.py
from main import thing
#bla-bla-bla
```

This would've worked if I declared thing as "hello world", for example. But it seems that all processing methods, including loadShape, must be used only inside or after the setup() method in main - otherwise they return NullPointerException.

So, I decided to wrap global variables in allglobal.py in a method, and call it from inside setup():

```
#####file: main.pyde
from control import allglobals
def setup():
  allglobals()
  #bla-bla-bla

def draw():
  #bla-bla-bla

#####file: allglobal.py
def allglobals():
  global thing
  thing = loadShape("param.svg")

#####file: control.py
from allglobals import thing
#bla-bla-bla
```

But now control cannot see the variable "thing": it stays undefined, or whatever.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get what I need done in processing.py?

Comment: Why is the suffix `.pyde`? It should be `.py`.

Comment: The main file in processing is .pyde file. It's not a mistake. It's an ordinary python file that must always contain the setup and draw processing methods - processing rules.

Maybe it's the reason it cannot be imported into other modules - only other modules can be imported into it.